# How to trigger an event on click of scroll bar in angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular5, scrollbar

In my project I have filter pop up to filter the data in the table. If I click any where outside the pop up in that table, pop up should close. The behavior is working properly when I click anywhere in the table. When scrollbar appear if I click on scrollbar it is not calling the function.

How to call the function on click of scroll bar in Angular 5.

Below is the `stackblitz` link please help me, thanks in advance.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uaig8q?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: If I were you I would change the architecture a little: when you open the pop up, scroll bar disappears (I.e you disallow scrolling until filtering is done)

Comment: That's also good one, but i want to close when scrolling. Can't we close pop up on scroll?

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the [`scroll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event. A solution not Angular specific is:

```
const myContainer = document.getElementById('my_element');
myContainer.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  filterPopup.close()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on Victor's answer, just add a scroll event listener on the entire window

```
 window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) { 
    popup.close();
 });
```